# IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found - After Windows 10 Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I'm quite confused that what happened to my `Web Api Application` or `IIS` after **Windows 10 Update**.

Some controllers like the following are working perfectly :

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test01/{str}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test01([FromUri]string str) {
        return Ok(str);
    }
}
```

But some others like this don't work and return `IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found`:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/companies")]
public class CompaniesController : ApiController {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test/{str}")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCompany([FromUri]string str) {
        return Ok(str);
    }
}
```

**Note:** I've removed updates of Windows and Visual Studio. Even reinstalled Visual Studio and restarted IIS from `windows features` but didn't make any change.

Now I'm thinking about reinstalling operating system. What's your suggestion?

**More Info:** I've tested it on my co-worker's machine and all its actions work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying lots of solutions related to `operating system`, `visual studio` and `iis`, I found the real problem which was caused by referencing another `web-api` project with the same controller names.

I'm not quiet sure whether it is a bug or not, I haven't expected such behavior, though.